# Including column of indices as predictor for model?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

I have a small dataset consisting of 1000 observations (rows), 11 predictors + 1 response (12 columns). It is a toy dataset used for learning purposes in a machine learning class at university -- binary classification (heart disease vs. no heart disease).

I have fitted a logistic regression, SVM, and KNN.
However, I am using python and I was deleting some rows corresponding to missing values and outliers I did not want to consider -- doing it with `df.drop()` and then `reset_index()`. If you do not set the drop flag of `reset_index` to `true` you will get a column in your data frame with the indices you wanted to reset. I accidentally forgot to set the flag to `true` and when fitting the 3 mentioned models included the column with these indices. This gave me an f1-score of 99-100%. When I realized that I had accidentally included this column, I dropped the column, re-fit and achieved ~ 60-80 percent F1 score with the respective models.

Is there a reason why including this column of indices gets you to 100% F1 score or even accuracy? Is this merely a coincidence that apparently works with the dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Including column of indices as predictor for model?

No, don't include indices. They don't provide any meaningful information about the problem. They are just an enumeration. Take them away.

> Is there a reason why including this column of indices gets you to 100% F1 score or even accuracy?

You probably get that when evaluating in train set, in test you wont get that. If you do, then you have a problem with your data (it might be sorted).

What does the underlying algorithm do here? Something like this for a decision tree

```
if index == 1:
 predict =1
if index == 2:
 predict =0
.
.
.
```

As you can see there is no meaningful information about the problem here and the prediction in train will still be zero.

**Conclusion**: don't use indexes as a training feature.